# "Cannot index into a null array" and "Invoke method on null" errors

Tags: powershell, calculated-column, script

I am new to SharePoint 2013 and am not a coder.

I have a List, "IRM Summary", that contains

- Date Opened,
- Date Closed
- Days Open and
- Today columns.

If there is a

```
Date Closed date, then Days Open = Date Closed-Days Open.
```

Else

```
Days Open = Today-Date Created.
```

This is working fine except that in SharePoint 2013, as I've found out, Today needs to be updated via a script and nightly scheduled task.

I've found the code below online (and several variations of it) and have adapted the names to our environment.

```
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite/sites/IRM
$list = $web.Lists[“IRM Summary”]
$list.Items | ForEach-Object {
$_[“Today”] = [System.DateTime]
$_.SystemUpdate($false)
$list.Update()
}
$web.Dispose()
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

However, when I run it in SharePoint 2013 Management Shell, I get the following errors:

> Cannot index into a null array. At C:\SPListItemsWithTodaysDate.ps1:26
>   char:1
>   + $_["Today"] = [System.DateTime] #Replace TodaysDate with your field name
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\SPListItemsWithTodaysDate.ps1:27 char:1
>   + $_.SystemUpdate($false)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   C:\SPListItemsWithTodaysDate.ps1:28 char:1
>   + $list.Update()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

The list itself is populated, and currently there are values in the Today column for every row in the list.

Any help would be appreciated, either with "fixing" the script or using another (non-Javascript) solution or workaround.

Comment: Might be just copy+paste issue, but FYI several sites format `"`-symbols with `“` `”`, which are not converted to default quotation marks when ran in command line.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my script was using the second type of quotation marks. Changed to the first type but getting the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
$_["Today"] = [System.DateTime]
```

apart from the `“` vs `"` quotes (which I believe are OK in your script as per the output), you need to assign a date object e.g. `$_["Today"] = [System.DateTime]::Today`. The `[System.DateTime]` expression represents the `DateTime` class, but it's not an instace of it.

Apart from that, the `$list.Update()` is only necessary when updating properties in the list. In this case you are updating items only, so no need for it.

Comment: Thanks Fran. Changing the line to $_["Today"] = [System.DateTime]::Today 
unfortunately produces the same result as before.

Comment: Please can you post the full code of your script?

Comment: The full code is as per the code block in my original post, just with the addition of "::Today" as you recommended above.
    Start-SPAssignment -Global
    $web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite/sites/IRM/teamroom
    $list = $spweb.Lists["IRM Summary"]
    $list.Items | ForEach-Object {
    $_["Today"] = [System.DateTime]::Today
    $_.SystemUpdate($false)
    $list.Update()
    }
    $web.Dispose()
    Stop-SPAssignment -Global

Comment: The one you just pasted here is slightly different to the one in the post (different URL, use of `$spweb` instead of `$web`). Also, the errors you are getting in powershell reference lines 26-28, the script you provide is shorter. I tested your example locally with a different URL and a different list name and works fine. Are you sure the list name is OK?. You could also add some checks like `$list.ItemCount`, `$list.Items.Count`, etc, to verify that the list exists and contains items